# Proguard warnings in Android project with multiple libraries

Tags: java, android, ant, proguard

In Android project with multiple libraries, Proguard produces following warnings:

> Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip
>   entry [some-library.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])

I have found in the [Proguard docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html#filtering) that it can be resolved by placing `(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)` filter to `-injars`.

It seems that that this is specified in ant file `android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml`.

What is the best (least invasive) way to override that behavior?

(I do not want just to copy whole ant target, since then it will require to maintain it with other updates of SDK.)

Comment: Hi man, did you solved it already? plz kindly tell me the result.

Comment: I have not yet found a good solution:(

Comment: Solved by adding "-injars", see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356595/why-eclipse-cant-write-resource/13360030#13360030

Comment: Into ant/build.xml specified above or somewhere else?

Comment: EDIT: FInally, I found: It is not compatible with Astrill（VPN）, I force closed astrill process and problems gone.