# Why Eclipse Can't Write Resource

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings

Eclipse CAN"T SIGN MY APP! But old version works fine.It just shows warnings below, is this a bug in juno version?

can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [ARMPlugin.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
...

Comment: I'm asking, can't you see? No other info, it only shows this kind of warnings. On another old computer, it would be fine.

Comment: @thecr0w: One, be nice. No need to be rude. You stand a better chance of getting solutions when you are _nice_ to users. And two, using CAPITAL letters is the equivalent of SHOUTING: http://www.netlingo.com/word/shouting.php

Comment: Sorry, but I did post this before. CAPITAL letters is not allowed in title? I will remember that next time.

Comment: Nope, capital words not allowed unless they are capitalised in your code. If you want to draw attention to something use **bold**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look through you `src` folders, and see if there is an unneeded `META-INF` folder. Delete this and it should work.

For more information on this see below

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-994

Comment: It has nothing to do with my src project, it is the eclipse I think. I can sign on my frends' computer, with the same project. I'm updating eclipse, it will be a long time.

Answer (score 0):

*-injars  android-support-v4.jar
-injars  library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) 
injars is NEEDED, But I don't understand why old eclipse don't need this.*

Edit:
No, It has nothing to do with "injar@#!!@...". I updated ADT, Eclipse. All Problem is gone.
(p.s.Eclipse Juno == Junk & Ugly :)

EDIT:
FInally, I found: It is not compatible with Astrill（VPN）, I force closed astrill process and problems gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the latest version of Eclipse ADT and android SDK (Versions 23.07.2013) proguard 4.7.

My workspace had two projects: my App and Google Play License. I noticed that the folder "lib" of my App was containing the JAR file that caused the error of duplication. I do not know where or why Eclipse put this file, but theoretically it was not necessary, as part of the standard Android RunTime, and being required to run Google Play License, the easier it was to directly reference a project to another.

Managed to solve by doing the following:

- I deleted the JAR that caused the error Lib folder.
- I clicked on Project Clean to clean the exits.
- In Project Properties, References, I checked Google Project License as direct reference.
- I did rebuid main project, my App
- When exporting with proguard no more errors occurred.

I can only assume that the reference of the folder Lib conflicted with the reference from Android standard runtime,  and that proguard interpreted the two in sequence, rather than doing a merge, resulting in doubling.